# concatenar y sumar en prolog

Tags: prolog, lógica, swi-prolog

una consulta estoy empezando en prolog y tengo un problema  al momento de concatenar , sumar y usar el format, lo que quiero hacer , es que los datos sean los nombres y si la operacion de las notas son  mayores a 11 como en el formato,salga  aprobo o desaprobo ,pero me sale error.

```
introducir el código aquí
%suma
promedio:- write('ingrese los datos:'),
            read(A),
            write('ingrese la nota1:'),
            read(B),
            write('ingrese la nota2:'),
            read(C),
            D is (B+C)/2,
            D>=11,D='Aprobado',
            D<11, D='Desaprobado',
            format(A,'tu estas ~w',[D]).
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que exiges que `D >= 11` y `D < 11` al mismo tiempo, y por lo tanto nunca se satisfará el predicado. Utiliza un condicional `(If -> Then ; Else)` para comprobar el valor de `D`:

```
promedio:-
    write('ingrese los datos: '), nl,
    read(A),
    write('ingrese la nota 1: '), nl,
    read(B),
    write('ingrese la nota 2: '), nl,
    read(C),
    D is (B+C)/2,
    write(A),
    (D >= 11 ->
        write(' estás aprobado');
        write(' estás suspenso')), nl.
```

Comment: Gracias  mi estimado, me ayudo mucho , entonces el format no es necesario?

Comment: Gracias  mi estimado, me ayudo mucho , entonces el format no es necesario?

Comment: Para esta tarea tan simple no es necesario, aunque puedes usarlo.